# Will it harm us if there are lots of other companies with the same name?

Tags: seo, backlinks, local-seo

We have a Charleston based business named Five Star Real Estate. We don’t have any other branch or office. There has no other business in our state with the same name. But there are lots of companies around the world with the same name.

*Lots of companies used our website address in their profile for different local directory submission sites. They also used our website address in different websites. That’s why we got lots of unexpected backlink.*

Is it bad for us? Will it harm us in SEO? Do we need to remove those backlinks? I am not sure will it harm us or not. Is there anyone who can suggest us about this issue?

Comment: Question might be about one specific website, but it applies for all websites really.

Comment: I edited and highlighted the real problem. The question is not really about inbound links (back links). It is about the added complication of business profiles created using links to their site. This can severely hamper SEO and may be a new method of negative SEO. In this regard, this may be a really important question for others. Who knows for sure?

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions in your explanation.

> backlink. Is it bad for us? Will it harm us in SEO?

You should look up 'bad backlinks' to learn more on the matter, and see your particular situation in further detail. Backlinks which are generated by websites that are not highly ranked by search engines will not themselves be much valued, and could even prove counter-productive.

> Do we need to remove those backlinks?

Ideally bad backlinks would better disappear altogether. However, since they are available from third-party websites, the trick is to have the links removed although you cannot action that yourself directly.

There is plenty of advice on this matter online. Browsing several sites on that particular issue won't do you any harm. Just make sure the content has been published as recently as possible.

Hope this is a useful answer.

Comment: This is the OP's real problem: *Lots of companies used our website address in their profile for different local directory submission sites. They also used our website address in different websites.* Backlinks being harmful is severely complicated by this. Cheers!!